# Derivation of Viterbi Algorithm

Tags: probability, optimization, algorithms, hidden-markov-models

I am trying to understand the derivation of the Viterbi algorithm for hidden Markov models. I understand that the motivation is to find the maximum probability path estimate, i.e.,

> \begin{equation}
>     \text{Choose } (\hat{X}_{k})_{k\le n} \text{ such that } 
>     \mathbf{P}[X_{k}=\hat{X}_{k} \text{ for all } k\le n] \text{ is maximized}.
> \end{equation}

We can use this lemma:

> Let $H: \mathbb{R}\to [0,\infty)$  be a loss function, $X$ be a real-valued
> random variable such that $\mathbf{E}[H(X)]<\infty$, and $Y$ be a
> $(\mathrm{B},\mathcal{B})$-valued random variable. Suppose there exists a
> $\mathcal{B}$-measurable function $g: B\to \mathbb{R}$ such that
> \begin{equation*}
>     g(y)=\displaystyle \arg\min_{\hat{x}\in \mathbb{R}} \int
>     H(x-\hat{x})P_{X|Y}(y,dx)
>     \text{ for all } y\in B '
> \end{equation*}
> where $B '\in \mathcal{B}$ such that $\mathbf{P}[Y\in B ']=1$. Then, $g$
> minimizes $\mathbf{E}[H(X-f(Y))]$.

Thus, if we choose our loss function to be $H(x)=I_0(x-\hat{x})$, to find the maximum probability path estimate, we choose the functions $f_{k}$ such that
\begin{equation*}
(f_{0}(y_{0: n}),\ldots,f_{n}(y_{0: n}))= \displaystyle 
\arg\max_{(\hat{x}_{0: n})} \int \prod_{k=0}^{n} I_{0}(x_{k}-\hat{x}_{k})
P_{X_{0: n}|Y_{0: n}}(y_{0: n}, dx_{0: n}).
\end{equation*}
However, the product in this last expression confuses me; it seems like the entire expression is simply 0. Is there a reasonable interpretation of why there's a product, or is it just a result of how we formulated the derivation?